# TypeError: e is undefined in popper.min.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I'm an working in Angular 8 and added Bootstrap via npm using below commands

`npm install jquery` 
`npm install popper.js` 
`npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap@4.1.1` 
 (have tried npm install bootstrap as well)

and updated my angular.json as below with styles and scripts.

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

            ]
```

I have added a code of drop-down in html file but its not working while checking in console I am getting popper.min.js error.

And the html script is :

```
<div class="col-6 text-left">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Project A
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project A</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project B</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project C</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project E</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

@Tony Ngo please find screenshot ( after changing order of popper and bootstrap)

[image]

Comment: When you run ng serve/ng build, does your application load js files which you had added to "scripts": ? You can check it in inspect -> network tab

Comment: don't use jquery etc. use a package made for Angular like https://ng-bootstrap.github.io or https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/

Comment: @Arash network tab not showing these scripts its only showing defaults scripts

Comment: @user1234 It should load whatever you add into **"styles": [** and **"scripts": [**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import order should be like this

```
 "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
 "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
```

Comment: Tried this one as well it gives new error as t is not defined in bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Can you take a screen shot for me ?

Comment: @TonyNgo I dont think that the order really matter.

Comment: @TonyNgo have added screenshot please check in my question

Comment: @user1234 would you mine click on arrow and expand it